# How do I query a relation database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this search query for Post model in Laravel:

`return $q ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')`

Which works totally fine. In my Post model I also have a relation database `categories`. This is available as an object in my returned post object.

Is there a way I can query the `category -> name`?

I have tried: 
`return $q ->where('category->name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')`

Comment: I believe you are looking for a `hasMany()` mapping in your Post Model. Please check the laravel docs for more information.

Comment: why `javascript` tag?

Comment: @ab_ab that's a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

For your use case you need to make sure you have the relationship established in your Post model. If that is set your query should look similar to the following:

```
return $q->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->whereHas('category', 
function ($query) use ($keyword) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
})->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're db is well structured - then will want to use Laravel's ORM for this stuff.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#introduction

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have **Models**:

1. Post
2. Category

Also that you have category_id as a foreign key in Post model.
This is basic structure.

I assume that you want to search Posts and Categories same time so you can do something like this:

```
return Post::leftJoin('categories', 'posts.category_id', '=', 'categories.id)
    ->where('categories.name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->orWhere('posts.title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
    ->get();
```